# How to fill something into list list

Tags: java, list, date

so i want to make a Calendar and want to use a list with Date Objects into a List

```
list<list<Date>>
```

but i wonder how to add the months into the first list and the days of each months into the inner list.

I tried to list.add() the elements but that wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to initialize your list of lists

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Date>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Date>>();
```

Second you need to add the list to your list of lists like so

```
data.add(new ArrayList<Date>());
```

Then after that you can add Date objects to that particular list at index 0 like so

```
data.get(0).add(new Date());
```

Example setup for 12 lists, one for each month

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    data.add(new ArrayList<Date>());
}

data.get(0) //is the list for January
data.get(5) //the list for June
data.get(11) //the list for December
```

To add a day to June you can do the following

```
data.get(5).add(new Date()); //adds a date to the list at index 5 (June)
```

Comment: So after 
`data.add(new ArrayList<Date>());`
i can simply add the months with
`data.add(the month);`
and add the days with 
`data.get(index of first list).add(new Date());`

Comment: added an example of how to grab certain lists and add dates to them, hope it helps @DeanJ.

Comment: Thank you alot @RAZ_Muh_Taz

Answer (score 0):

so you can definitely do what you want via the method RAZ_Muh_Taz suggested. However are you sure that's what you want? by the sound of things to me you would be better off with a different data structure altogether, like a map:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("January", new list<date>());
map.get("January"); # = your date
```

To me this more closely fits what you're trying to do :).